# Average count of overlap between random samples

Tags: sampling, mean, expected-value, overlapping-data

If I randomly sample `n` numbers from `1..m`, `x` times, what would be the average count of numbers that overlap in every sample?

Example:

- Variables: `n = 4`, `m = 12`, `x = 3`
- Samples: `4 8 1 11`, `5 4 12 1`, `1 3 7 4`
- Numbers that overlap in every sample: `2` (1 and 4)

I think I have a general intuition on how you might do this for `x = 2`. My thought is that you want to find the probabilities for all possible counts, `0..n`, and then you could use those probabilities to do a weighted average of the counts? And to do those probabilities, you'd do something like `1 / choose(count, m)`, except for `count = 0` which is `1-(1/choose(n,m))`? It's been a while since I took stats so I wouldn't be surprised if that intuition is wrong though.  But even if it is right, I'm still not sure how you would go about doing it for `x > 2`/generalizing for all `x`.

*From comments:*

> What is the probability a particular number, e.g. $1$, appears in the first sample?

It would be $n/m$, so for my example, $30\%$ probability that $1$ appears in the first sample

> What is the probability it appears in all $x$ samples?

I think it would be $(n/m)^x$

> What is the expected number of numbers that appear in all $x$ samples?

I can understand that I should now have the information needed to answer this, but I think this is beyond my current capabilities.

Comment: Is each sample of $n$ from $1,2,\ldots,m$ without replacement?

Comment: Hint: What is the probability a particular number, e.g. $1$, appears in the first sample? What is the probability it appears in all $x$ samples?  What is the expected number of numbers that appear in all $x$ samples?

Comment: Each number can only appear in a sample once. So for my example, a sample of `1 1 1 1` is not possible. But you could have 4 samples of `1 2 3 4`.

Comment: > What is the probability a particular number, e.g. 1, appears in the first sample?

It would be `n/m`, so for my example, 30% probability that 1 appears in the first sample

Comment: > What is the probability it appears in all x samples?

I think it would be `(n/m)^x`?

Comment: > What is the expected number of numbers that appear in all x samples?

I can understand that I should now have the information needed to answer this, but I think this is beyond my current capabilities.

Comment: Why do you need a closed-form solution?  You can just simulate the process and obtain an estimate for any $m,n,x$ combination as follows.  1) Obtain a random sample of the datasets, 2) code a function to calculate the number of overlaps (cardinality of intersection of $x$ sets), 3) repeat a large number of times, 4) calculate the sample average number of overlaps

Comment: @user277126 yes, I could most definitely do that! But knowing/understanding the closed-form solution is equally interesting to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found the probability a particular number appears in all $x$ samples to be $(n/m)^x$

Linearity of expectation means that the expected number of numbers that appear in all $x$ samples is simply that probability multiplied by the number of possible numbers $(m)$, giving an expectation of $$m\left(\frac n m\right)^x = \frac{n^x}{m^{x-1}}$$

For example, when $x=1$ it gives the obviously correct $n$.  For $x=2$ it gives $\frac{n^2}{m}$ which you might want to check.  For your example of $n = 4$, $m = 12$, $x = 3$ it gives $\frac 49 \approx 0.444$ as the expected number

Comment: @user277126 When  $n=2, m=3, x=2$, there must be at least one overlap so the expectation must be at least $1$.  In fact there are ${3 \choose 2}^2=9$ equally likely possibilities for the two draws, $3$ of  which have  two overlaps and the other $6$ have one overlap.  So the expectation number of overlaps is $2 \times \frac{3}{9} +1 \times{6}{9}=\frac{12}{9}=\frac43$ which is indeed $ \frac{n^x}{m^{x-1}}$

Comment: @user277126 The cases with two overlaps are $(\{1,2\},\{1,2\})$, $(\{1,3\},\{1,3\})$, $(\{2,3\},\{2,3\})$. The cases with one overlap are $(\{1,2\},\{1,3\})$, $(\{1,3\},\{2,3\})$, $(\{2,3\},\{1,2\})$, $(\{1,2\},\{2,3\})$, $(\{1,3\},\{1,2\})$, $(\{2,3\},\{1,3\})$.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I am doing it with replacement

Comment: @user277126 A comment from the OP said without replacement.  With replacement the answer would be $m\left(1-\left(1- \frac1m\right)^n\right)^x$ which in the case of $n=2, m=3, x=2$ I think would give $\frac{25}{27} \approx 0.9259$

Comment: @user277126 my simulation is close to my combinatorial result. And I can justify it: with replacement there are $\left(3^2\right)^2 = 81$ equally likely draws (so I do not intend to list them), $12$ of which have two distinct overlaps, $51$ have one distinct overlap and $18$ have no overlap, giving an expectation of  $2 \times \frac{12}{81} +1 \times\frac{51}{81}+0 \times\frac{18}{81}=\frac{75}{81}=\frac{25}{27}$.

Comment: @Henry ah ok. I just did some reading on linearity of expectation. I think I remember learning that many years ago. Now that I have relearned it, your answer makes a lot of sense. Thank you for helping reawaken some of my probability & statistics skills today.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach.  Let $\mathcal{S}_i$ denote the set of $n$ numbers (taken from $m$ numbers without replacement) for dataset $i$, where $i=1, \cdots, x$.  Let $\mathcal{S}_U = \bigcap_{i=1}^x \mathcal{S}_i$, then the expected number of overlaps between the $x$ datasets (assuming $n \le m$) is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^n i \,\mbox{Pr} \left[|\mathcal{S}_U|=i\right],
\end{eqnarray*}
where $|\cdot|$ denotes the cardinality of a set.

This can be re-written in the form
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i_1=1}^m \mbox{Pr} \left[\mathcal{S}_U=\{i_1\}\right] + 2\sum_{i_1=1}^{m-1}\sum_{i_2=i_1+1}^m \mbox{Pr} \left[\mathcal{S}_U=\{i_1, i_2\}\right] + \cdots + n \sum_{i_1}\cdots\sum_{i_n}\mbox{Pr} \left[\mathcal{S}_U=\{i_1,\cdots, i_n\}\right].
\end{eqnarray*}

Upon collecting terms, this may be re-written as the previous answer suggests
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^m \mbox{Pr} \left[i \in \mathcal{S}_U \right].
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Hi @user277126 thanks for the solution! I think this is actually closer to how I was originally approaching the problem in my head. 

Comment: @rolledback Thought you might like it